Package Platform Event in managed package
I want to package a platform event in managed package.
I know that after doing this my package cannot be installed in Professional or Group edition orgs. But I also see following while uploading my managed package:

So does all salesforce orgs which are not Professional, or group edition have this feature enabled by default or is it something that needs to be enabled separately.
My package is created and supported only for orgs that are not Professional or Group edition, could there be any scenario where this package installation still fails after adding platform event to my package.
Edit 1: I read the provided question in comment:
Can a Managed Package with Platform Events work in a Professional Edition Org
It does not answer my question because I specifically want to know about the features mentioned in the image above:

API and Platform Events
API and High Volume Platform Events

I am unaware if these features are directly linked with different editions of an org, i.e., not present in Professional or Group edition, and present in other editions.

This question is similar to: Can a Managed Package with Platform Events work in a Professional Edition Org. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Platform Events are available (as per documentation) in all Performance, Unlimited, Enterprise and Developer editions without the need to have it separately enabled.
This warning is simply indicating your package won't be compatible with Professional and Group edition orgs.
The only other scenario I can think of is where the org has already consumed all available Platform Event definitions. See the documentation for more detail on allocations. Specifically consider the note toward the end of the page:

Platform events that originate from an installed managed package share the org’s allocation for the maximum number of platform event definitions.

Note, however, that Salesforce doesn't always rigidly apply limits (some limits have become what they call "soft limits", with a larger and unpublished "hard limit" capping out what you can do).

Even though the provided documentation mentions that the limit includes PEs from managed package but still I tried on developer edition org and created 5 PEs, then installed the package and it got installed with the PE I packaged. So now I have 6 PEs in my developer edition org

In terms of the org you used, was this a Partner Developer org? If so, these have different limits.

Hey Phil, the org in which I installed the package is a normal Developer Edition org.
The one in which I create the package is also Developer Edition only I think, not sure how to identify if it is Partner Developer org, I cannot enable Dev Hub in it as it shows "You can't enable Dev Hub in a Developer Edition org with a registered namespace", and also the Data Storage limit is 5MB and File Storage limit is 20MB, so I think it is just normal Developer Edition org

I do hope you are not using your PBO for package development. I note from your other Q&A you have developed a 1GP (and I wonder why you did that, if the package is new). These require a "packaging org" which is where the package versions are "uploaded". The best way to address such development is to use the sf CLI and SFDX best practice, using scratch orgs for work item development (e.g. if you use Jira to track work, create a new scratch org for each Jira issue you work on) and storing the package metadata in version control (e.g. git via github or another service). To Be Continued...

You then deploy the metadata from a git checkout to your packaging org, ensure that the required metadata is part of the package (using the UI you showed in the other Q&A) and upload the new package version. The packaging org in this instance would be a developer org with the package's namespace created on it. Your scratch orgs can share the namespace by ensuring that your PBO (which is your DevHub) has the namespace registered against it and then referencing the namespace in your project-scratch-def.json. I strongly recommend you read up on the SFDX "modern" development practices for SF.
